# Connect synchronously to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to connect to mongodb first, then run everything else in my application.

To do it I have to write something like:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/test", function(err, connection) {
    if (err) { console.error(err); }
    db = connection;

    var app = express();

    // Include API V1
    require("./apiv1.js")(app, db);

    app.listen(3000, function(err) {
        if (err) { console.error(err); } else { console.log("Started on *:3000"); }
    });
});
```

This makes my app to be completely indented inside the .connect function... Which looks ugly and takes space while I work on my project.

I think the best solution would be have the MongoDB connection synchronous (even because witout the DB connection my app cannot work so why should I do something while it's connecting?) and then run the rest of my code.

How can I do?

Comment: This is how node.js works. Everything is async and callback-ridden. You can't change that, but I remember reading about some libs that would help with reducing spaghetti-ness of the code. Unfortunately, I can't remember the names.

Comment: "the best solution would be have the MongoDB connection synchronous" - you could use ruby, for example.

Comment: Yes, your app is wrapped inside the `.connect()` method, but you export all the logic in another file (which is a good idea) and I can not see anything ugly here.

Comment: You might want to have a look into [koa](http://koajs.com), which makes code look much cleaner ( at the expense of heavy use of ES6 generator functions ).

Comment: You can use `mongoose`, it has IMO a great feature that if you try to save something, it waits until the connection is established and then, behind the scenes, saves the data!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can't connect to MongoDB synchronously, but you may get rid of this ugly callback from your code.

The best way to do it is to adopt some wrapper around [`node-mongodb-native` driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native).

Take a look at the following modules.

---

### [mongojs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs)

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('localhost/test');
var mycollection = db.collection('mycollection');
```

---

### [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin)

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", {native_parser:true});
```

---

### [monk](https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk)

```
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost/test');
var users = db.get('users')
```

---

Of course, internally all of them are establishing MongoDB connection asynchronously.

Comment: Hey mongoskin is awesome! Thank you ^_^

Comment: @FezVrasta I personally prefer `monk`, but they all are great. =)

Comment: well, mongoskin lets me plug-in it without have to change all my code, it's a nice +1 for this module

Comment: Coming here in 2019, monk is still active and worked first try.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `async` library, you can aleve some of these issues.

For example in my server startup I do the following :

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        // Initialize the mongodb connection and callback on completion in init.
        db.init(function(){
            callback();
        });
    },
    function(callback){
        // Listen on requests etc.
        webServer.init(function(){
            callback();    
        });
    },
    function(callback){
        // Set up anything else that I need
        callback();
    }
]);
```

Comment: Yes. Use async if your code absolutely has to be synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node 6 and up versions, you can do something like this:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb';
let db = null;
getdb();

//your code

async function getdb() {
     db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
}
```

1. Bring the mongodb library.
2. Declare the url constant .
3. Declare the variable db as null.
4. Call the getdb function.
5. Create the getdb function which has firt the async word
6. Assign to the db variable the result of the connection with the key word await.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer the question. This code is still async

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [thunky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/thunky), thunky executes an async function once and caches it, the subsequent calls are returned from the cache.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const thunky = require('thunky');

var connect = thunky(function(cb){
 let url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client){
    console.log('connecting')
    cb(err, client);
 })
})

connect( (err, client) => {
  console.log('connection 1')
})

connect( (err, client) => {
  console.log('connection 2')
})

connect( (err, client) => {
  console.log('connection 3')
  console.log('closing')
  client.close();
})
```

*Note: I am using latest 3.x mongodb driver